# How to reach elements inside of 2 <iframe> using Selenium WebDriver? Looking for elegant code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've got webpage with  tags, this is simplified extract:

```
<body>
...
<iframe id="outFrame">
    <iframe id ="innerFrame">
        <div id="myDiv">Some text</div>
    </iframe>
</iframe>
...
</body>
```

I made a properly wortking code looking like that:

```
WebElement frame = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("outFrame")));
WebElement hexagon = new WebDriverWait(driver.switchTo().frame(frame).switchTo().frame("innerFrame"), 10)
        .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDiv")));
```

And that looks like not an elegant piece of code. Any suggestions how to get  element in more decent way? Let's image how awfull my code can be if  won't get proper id!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`()

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("outFrame")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("innerFrame")));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDiv")));
```

Comment: Do I have to reset `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` to get back to original state of driver?